# Setting default for Solr faceting

Tags: solr, facet

I was wondering how I can enable faceting in the solr config without being forced to put it all the times in the URL. Secondly how can set the number of fields?
thanks

Comment: have a look at my answer. What do you mean by setting the number of fields?

Comment: @javanna sorry I mean the number of facets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass all the default parameters you need to your request handler like this:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="facet">true</str>
        <str name="facet.field">field1</str>
        <str name="facet.field">field2</str>
        <str name="facet.field">field3</str>
   </lst>        
</requestHandler>
```

This way you have facet enabled by default for `field1`, `field2` and `field3`.